# C: Read hex written in ASCII

Tags: c, file-io, hex

I wish to write a C program that reads in 1 byte hex values stored in a file. I have had a look around the Internet including StackOverflow but my requirement seems different from the average:

I have a text file with the following contents - which are single byte hex values:

```
35 36 37 38
```

In decimal that is:

```
53, 54, 55, 56
```

The hex values are the following ASCII characters

```
5 6 7 8
```

I want to read that in from a text file the which contains the ASCII `35 36 37 38` as four hex bytes. I have been tinkering with `FILE` pointers and `fread()` but it reads in the `35` value for example as `3` and `5` which is stored in a buffer as `33 35` (the hex for `3` and `5` separately). So my question is...

**Short version**:

Is there a way to read a file two ASCII characters at a time (not two bytes at a time because that would give different results!). Perhaps should I read into a char? Rather than presenting some code and stating it doesn't work as usually happens on SO, I'm not sure how to start with this so I have no code to present. You don't have to write the code for me but some guidance on how to approach the problem scenario would be good.

Comment: What about the spaces?

Comment: A person of your stature should know the score - you need to write some code and let us comment/fix it.

Comment: @EdHeal - Why  should one have to post code? Is it forbidden on StackOverflow to talk about how to approach a programming problem? Can we not discuss the logic of the problem, pseudo code even?

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%x", &h)` ... `printf("%c ", (char)h);`

Comment: @KerrekSB - Good point about the spaces, I'd like to ignore them, I'll update the post. Regarding the "is there a way" - again I should have been clearer on that too, I meant `is there a way that doesn't involve some really obscure or non-constructive code like casting to an int which is cast to base 16 and then cast to a popsicle and then printed from printf() into cout()`

Comment: Its fair to say my question is a duplicate of the post linked by the moderators but have you read all the answers - some of those are not good answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible to read two characters at a a time:

```
unsigned int dehex(FILE * p)
{
    char two[2];
    if (2 != fread(two, 1, 2, p)) { abort(); }

    return as_hex(two[0]) * 16 + as_hex(two[1]);
}

unsigned int as_hex(char c)
{
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') { return c - '0'; }
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') { return c + 10 - 'a'; }
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') { return c + 10 - 'A'; }
    abort();
}
```